# New Hard Drive increasing RPMs over time on OSX

Tags: macos, hard-drive

My new replacement hard drive slowly rams up the RPM speed. Its looks like linear growth, from a poorly written program but I just erased it and reinstalled OS X to make sure it wasn't a software bug from my previous installation. It has the same problem. Activity monitor doesn't show a process using much of the Disk either.

Its named "SATA Disk" and I got it from a repairman. I'm worried its a bad disk or a bad install but want to ask if someone else has seen the problem before in hopes that I can fix the problem myself instead of going back to the repair man.

It gets noisy over time and the picture shows that the RMPs of the hard drive slowly increase over time. This picture from iStat Menus shows the linear growth in RPMs over time.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Its unlikely a bad disk.  Without the exact model name.  We can't really explain the behavior.  My guess its likely a "green" drive which attempts to save power, thus when you access the drive, it has to spin back up.

Comment: poked around a bit and found this as my hard drive: WDC WD10EZEX-08M2NA0 Media

Comment: As I suspected `Western Digital WD Blue` products attempt to save energy.  They are not as bad as Green drive but still pretty bad.  I suggest doing a benchmark on the drive.  To be honest I would just replace the drive.  You might want to talk to Apple to find out what they suggest.

Answer (score 0):

So after a few hours of looking for an answer I found some other people experiencing the same problem. It is software related.

First off Apple:
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Secondly from a third party piece of software that ended up fixing the problem:
http://www.hddfancontrol.com/imac-hard-drive-replacement-fan-noise-issue/

> Since the late 2009 iMacs came out, replacing the hard drive has caused the internal Hard Drive Fan to start running at around 6000RPM.
>
> This is due to Apple replacing the external Hard Drive temperature sensor with a proprietary firmware and using the drives internal sensor.

Thirdly a free bit of software that also might fix other peoples problems:
https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl

I ended up buying "HDD Fan Control" since it worked immediately and didn't take any setup like "smcFanControl". Seems like using [SMART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T) is a good replacement for Apple's special firmware

I hope this helps others out there that are hearing to much fan noise after they replace their hard-drive.

Comment: Wait, so this is the ***fan*** and not the HDD at all?

Comment: Yeah the fan, I figured it was the disk speeding up at first, 5200 being a common speed for a disk right? And that graph goes to 5500 so I thought 'well hey maybe there is some leeway to the maximum disk speed in this graph.' After more research I found my disk can go to 7200 RPMs, and the fan can go to 5500 that iStat menu screenshoot doesn't label the graphs very well so I misunderstood it. Anyways if your hard disk speeds up I doubt you'll hear the disk, not enough air in there to make much noise, instead its probably the fans making the noise.